# Create new page in code behind Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

Currently in Windows Phone 8.1 if I want to navigate to a new Page, first I must create a new Page item - `MyNewPage` - that produces a XAML and CS file. The in order to navigate to it I do the following:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MyNewPage));
```

Now, I want to know if it is possible to create a new Page in code behind and navigate to it, something like:

```
Page myNewPage = new Page();
Frame.Navigate(typeof(myNewPage));
```

Since the Navigate method only accepts a `typeof()`, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `myNewPage.GetType()`? That would pass in an `Page`, so not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: It makes sense, but does not work. **UPDATE:** Actually it does work, I was doing it wrong. Please post an answer so I can accept it. And thanks! :)

Comment: Funny thing was I was making a wild guess. I'm not going to make an answer based on that. Someone else (or yourself) can pick that up.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for your wild guess! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@gunr2171's wild guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163922/create-new-page-in-code-behind-windows-phone-8-1#comment41017910_26163922), I was able to make it work. So the final code looks like this:

```
Page myNewPage = new Page();
Type pageType = myNewPage.GetType();
Frame.Navigate(pageType);
```

or to make it simpler:

```
Page myNewPage = new Page();
Frame.Navigate(myNewPage.GetType());
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx) says that you can pass any object as a 2nd parameter for the another version of Frame.Navigate method. I think you can use it (i suggest that you want to fill some properties from code behind from your new page or smth...). Also you can access your page from Frame after navigation. Think about it, it may helps.

```
var root = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        var mainPage = root.Content as Page;
```

Comment: It is a good suggestion @PolarBear, but for my scenario I need to be able to do everything in code and just sending the second parameter is not enough for me.